# Extending automorphisms from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ over general rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Over an algebraically closed field any automorphism of the affine line will extend uniquely to an automorphism of the projective line. Will that still be true if we work over a general (potentially non reduced) ring?

Comment: No, it's not. Take a field $K$ and put $R:=K[\varepsilon ]/(\varepsilon ^2)$. Then $x\mapsto x+\varepsilon x^2$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^1_R$ which does not extend to an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1_R$.

Comment: @abx Are you sure? It seems to me that when $\varepsilon^2=0$ then this is the fractional linear transformation $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1-\varepsilon x}$. (In the other affine line with coordinate $y=1/x$ it is $y\mapsto y-\varepsilon$.)

Comment: @Tom Goodwillie: Oops, you are right of course! It should be $x\mapsto x+\varepsilon x^n$ with $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Answers can be posted as answers :)

Comment: Thanks @abx! Is there a description of $Aut \mathbb{A}^1$ as an ind group scheme?

Comment: Yes, this has been worked out (more generally for $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^n) $) by Shafarevitch, *On some infinite-dimensional groups II*, Math. USSR-Izvestyia, Vol. 18, 1982, pp. 185-194.

Comment: The paper seems to deal only with k points, no? The conclusion there for n=1 is it's just affine transformations